# How to install remastersys on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, remastersys

I have install ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP laptop. Now, I want to get back up my Ubuntu OS along with the installed packages of Ubuntu . I want to do this with the help of **remastersys** software. Now, while I installing the same by using these commands ,

1) `wget https://transfer.sh/Zf0OF/remastersys-gui.tar.gz`

2) `tar -zxvf remastersys-gui.tar.gz`

3) `cd remastersys-gui`

4) `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

5) `sudo apt-get install -f`

What can I do ? Please help.

Comment: In my hp laptop with edubuntu 14.04 LTS OS , while I tried the 1st command , the following message occurs ---   **" --2015-11-22 20:26:59--  https://transfer.sh/Zf0OF/remastersys-gui.tar.gz
Resolving transfer.sh (transfer.sh)... 54.72.196.99, 54.246.179.160
Connecting to transfer.sh (transfer.sh)|54.72.196.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2015-11-22 20:27:00 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error. "**

Comment: internal server error , means it may be of internet connection issue or other LAN issues .

Answer (score 1):

The documentation about remastersys can be found [here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/remastersys).

Here is how to install remastersys, type the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mutse-young/remastersys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remastersys remastersys-gtk
```

Then to open the application, type in `remastersys-gtk` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need **ubiquity** to be installed.
If your system has 64-bit architecture install **libxmu6** before installing **ubiquity**:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu6:i386
```

Then add 32-bit support:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

After that install **ubiquity** via **Synaptic**, and install **remastersys** (or **Pinguy Builder**).